# Factorize a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, prime-factoring, factorization

I have learnt an algorithm of factorizing numbers in C++ and Java, now decided to "translate" it into JS. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Factorization</title>
  <script>
 function fact(num)
 {
    var b = 2;
    while (num > b){
    while(num%b==0){
    num/=b;
    return b;
    }
    b++;
    if(num==b){
    return b;
    }
    }
 }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form name="f1">
  Enter the Number  :<input type="number" name="txt1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Factorize" onclick="alert('The answer is ' + fact(txt1.value))">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong w it? It only alerts the 1st multiple.

P/S A working algorithm in C++ is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    int b=2;
    while(a>b){
        while(a%b==0){
            a/=b;
            cout << b << endl;
        }
        b++;
        if(a==b){
            cout << b << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling the `return` statement when the 1st factor is found. So naturally the program control exits the function. Instead, store the factors in an array and return the whole array at the end.

Answer (score 3):

The return statement exits the function as pointed out by @Blaze Sahlzen, consider constructing and returning a string instead:

```
function fact(num)
{
    let b = 2;
    let ans = "\n";
    while (num > b){
        while(num%b==0){
            num/=b;
            ans += b + '\n';
        }
        b++;
        if(num==b){
            ans += b + '\n';
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are exiting the function at first multiple. You can have a look on the below code, it will help you.

```js
function fact(num)
 {
    var b = 2;
 var factors =1;
 if(num==b){
      return b;
    }
    while (num > b){
      if(num % b == 0)
   {
   factors +=','+b;
   }
 b++;
   }
   factors +=','+num;
   return factors;
 }
```

```html
 <form name="f1">
  Enter the Number  :<input type="number" name="txt1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Factorize" onclick="alert('The answer is ' + fact(txt1.value))">
  </form>
```